# Compiling groovy in eclipse gives compile time error

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I'm on a project that I didn't start but have inherited some stuff to maintain.  The code is java with some groovy mixed in.  I'm using Eclipse... I know how to spell "groovy" but that's about it but it's been fine so far...
The issue:

Using java 8, Eclipse Oxygen (with Groovy 2.5.7 compiler) this code that looks like compiles with no problem:

```
class Bgc<T extends Bgc> {
    protected StartListener sln
    interface StartListener
    {
      void onStarted(T cmd)
    }
    
    T onStarted(StartListener startListener)
    {
      this.sln = startListener 
      (T)this
    }
}
```

FWIW our build scripts have no problem building this construct either... but if I try to build this in Eclipse 4.10.0, java 11.  My eclipse claims to have the 2.5.14 compiler and the 3.0 compiler for groovy... neither choice works in this java 11 capable eclipse...  Eclipse 4.10.0 just gives me an error in the "StartListener" interface, complaining that the onStarted(T cmd) is making a reference to the non-static type T.

I don't understand if Eclipse Oxygen/Java 8/groovyc 2.5.7 (which allows this to build) is simply ignoring the "T" in ...(T cmd) or if the newer java/groovyc or not.  If the earlier combo is ignoring it, then I can (presumably) just remove "T".

Answer (score 0):

An inner interface is a static inner class so it cannot refer to any of the type parameters of its outer class(es). Only non-static members can reference T.

Comment: So that would seem to indicate that the earlier versions of eclipse/java/groovyc was actually ignoring the type designation??  Is there a way to prove that, other than the fact one builds it and the other doesn't?

Comment: You could set up the same situation in a Java source and see what the compiler says.